# How to configure outlook emails with Liberty server

Tags: outlook, websphere-liberty

There is a Websphere liberty server (linux) and I'm planning to configure outlook mails on that server for triggering a script upon receiving a specific type of email.
How can we make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I could see doing this at least two ways.  You could consider using a Outlook script rule.  If that won't work, you'll have to write an application that runs on Liberty, connects to Outlook and checks for new mail.  If found, you'll have to parse the mail to determine if it meets your criteria and if so, invoke your script.